# Wipe Application Data Only

Tags: android, security, policy

I'm Developing a 'Security' Application and I'm currently using Device Policy Manager. I can successfully do a wipe, but I'm looking to wipe all application data only or wipe data from the specified App Ex. : wipe Kik Messenger Data (Conversation , Login ...) and keep all applications (especially My Application) I don't want a full Factory Reset or wipe /Data/App/, is there any way to do this? Also, no matter if the device requires root access for your given solution (if you have one).

Comment: if you have root access , you can always delete /data/data to reset app data

Comment: and, there is no way to do this without root permissions

Comment: ok thanks you for your answer , i never used Root on my Apps , i want to add this ability to Rooted Devices and keep my App Working on Non-Rooted Devices , so how do you Delete a specified Folder with Root ? can i add a Statement if(String.Equals("com.My.App"){Ignore} ?

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare for your Help in all my Questions , Peoples like you are Important, as many peoples here , i respect the way you think .